# В чем разница между передачей в setState объекта и функции и зачем вообще передавать функцию?

Tags: reactjs

В чем разница и что дает передача функции, а не объекта в setState?

```
this.setState( state => ({
    clicked: true
}));
```

```
this.setState({
    clicked: true
});
```

Comment: Ты выбрал неудачный пример... Сделай счетчик. Отображение и кнопку, при нажатии счетчик увеличивается на единицу. Затем быстро сделай несколько кликов - увидишь разницу в работе этих стейтов. ;)

Comment: `что дает передача функции` гарантированную работу с предыдущим стейтом. Функция его получает как параметр.

Answer (score 1):

Передача функции в состояния дает возможность получить предыдущее значение состояния даже если оно еще не ререндерилось.

[**Пример**](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-colden-w8qo2n?file=/src/App.js):

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  }

  updateCounter = () => {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1});
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1});
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.updateCounter}>update</button>
        {this.state.counter}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Такой код в конечном итоге увеличит счетчик только на единицу. Это похоже на `this.setState({ counter: 1});`, `this.setState({ counter: 1});` поэтому `counter` становится равным 1, а не 2.

Когда вы передаете объект в `setState`, React объединяет его со старым состоянием компонента. Если в объекте присутствуют свойства, которые уже существуют в состоянии, то они будут заменены новыми значениями, а остальные свойства останутся неизменными. *При этом React может объединять обновления состояния для оптимизации производительности.*

Использование функции обратного вызова дает возможность получить предыдущее состояние.

[**Пример**](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-austin-9b5kr0?file=/src/App.js:36-475):

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  };

  updateCounter = () => {
    this.setState((previusState) => ({
      counter: previusState.counter + 1
    }));
    this.setState((previusState) => ({
      counter: previusState.counter + 1
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.updateCounter}>update</button>
        {this.state.counter}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Как и было задумано будет увеличивать счетчик на 2, а не на 1.

Когда вы передаете функцию в `setState`, React вызывает эту функцию, передавая ей текущее состояние в качестве аргумента. Функция должна вернуть новый объект состояния. Этот подход полезен, когда новое состояние зависит от предыдущего. React гарантирует, что вызовы функций `setState` будут объединены воедино и обработаны последовательно.